# Why does "div[class=mncls sbucls]" work whereas "div.mncls sbucls" doesn't?

Tags: html, html-parsing, jsoup

The following Jsoup statement works:

```
 Elements divs = document.select("div[class=mncls sbucls]");
```

But the equivalent statment:

```
 Elements divs = document.select("div.mncls sbucls");
```

Doesn't work.

Why?

Does Jsoup have a problem with class names that have spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A space is a descendent selector:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors

In your second example, when you put the space in there, you're denoting another element/class/selector, whereas in your first example you're explicitly grouping the selector into a single string (including the space).

Answer (score 1):

Class names can not have a space. It's a CSS Specification, nothing to do with Jsoup. Technically `mncls sbucls` is two separate classes (`mncls` and `sbucls`).

The attribute selector works because you're selecting the `class` attribute where the value is `mncls sbucls`